# MySQL filter, count, arrange

Tags: mysql

I have a table like this

```
user  |  app
name1   app1
name1   not an app
name1   app1
name1   app2
name2   not an app
name3   app2
name3   app3
name4   app3
name4   app3
```

and I need to extract users where the apps are different

```
user  |  app
name1   app1
name1   app2
name3   app2
name3   app3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using a self join should work based on equivalent user and non-equivalent app excluding 'not an app' records

As the results would grow exponentially to the number of variances in app per user, we use group by to limit the results down to one occurrence each.

```
SELECT A.user, A.App
FROM table A
INNER JOIN table B
  on A.User = B.user 
 and A.App <> B.App
 and A.App <> 'not an app'
 and B.App <> 'not an app'
Group by A.user, A.App
```

Appears to work..

[image]

Comment: I haven't tried this but I need to show all occurrences as long as the app is an app and is not already shown

Comment: So if App 4, App4, App1 existed for user 1 you would want to see App4 listed twice and app1 listed once for the same user?

Comment: Looks like it would, I have another doubt tho, I use WHERE LIKE because I search for string that contain particular values, this way:

`WHERE app LIKE \"%@%\"
OR app LIKE \"%Desktop%\"
OR publishedapp LIKE \"%RDP%\"`

How could I implement something like this with INNER JOIN?

Something like this?

`and A.App <> B.App
 and A.App <> \"%@%\"
 and A.App <> \"%Desktop%\"
 and A.App <> \"%RDP%\"`
 and B.App <> \"%@%\"
 and B.App <> \"%Desktop%\"
 and B.App <> \"%RDP%\`

Comment: Apologies I just realized <> (doesn't contain), so something like this rather:

`and A.App <> B.App
 and A.App "%@%"
 and A.App "%Desktop%"
 and A.App "%RDP%"
 and B.App "%@%"
 and B.App "%Desktop%\
 and B.App "%RDP%"`

Answer (score 1):

Filtering out 'not an app' records, this will get you users that have more than one app:

```
select user
from MyTable
where app <> 'not an app'
group by user
having count(distinct app) > 1
```

You can then use this to retrieve all the data for those users like this:

```
select *
from MyTable
where user in (
    select user
    from MyTable
    where app <> 'not an app'
    group by user
    having count(distinct app) > 1
)
```

Comment: Sorry, how do I implement this, do I copy the first query to a new table and the query that new table with the second query?

Comment: You just need the 2nd query.